# how to stop value event listener from listening after a condition is met

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

for example searching in circles for a user circle if a data exist I want it DO process 1 and if data doesn't exist I want it to create one then DO process 2 ... but what happens in this code if data doesn't exist it will create one then do process 2 then go back then do process 1 after checking. so how can I stop the listener after process 2.
sorry if the circles example is too ambiguous but this is the simplest example I could think of .

```
Firebase ref= new Firebase("https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com/circles/");
Query queryRef = ref.orderByChild("circalename").equalTo(user.circalename);
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {
        if (datasnapshot.exists()) { // I don't want to get back here after 
                                      //creating the data in the else statement 
             // DO process 1
         }

         // if my data doesnt exist I will create one after that STOP listening 
         else {
             // create circle 
             // do process 2
         }

    }
```

Comment: You'll want to remove the listener to stop receiving updates. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-detaching

Comment: yes exactly!!  how can I remove it inside itself ?

Comment: You have a `listener` variable. So `queryRef.removeEventListener(listener)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 9):

What you can do is use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`

as it listens to the event only once

i.e. in your case

```
queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        if (datasnapshot.exists()) {
            // code if data exists
        } else {
            // code if data does not  exists
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Okay it will listens one time, but the Question is "how to stop value event listener from listening after a condition is met" means how to remove ValueEventListener if query with 'equalTo("")','orderByChhild("")' like this, because the onDataChangeListener is alive event the activity is finished, so we need to remove ValueEventListener onDestoy of activity

Comment: @Gururaj, You are correct on your follow up comment. I understood the situation when I ran into the same problem. Well, if its a global variable, then that listener could be removed in onDestryoy or onStop as you said. However, what worked for me and you should try it too is: call  queryRef.removeEventListener(this); from inside onDataChange when your condition is met. But this is a good question as i feel every Firebase developer must get a hang of!

Answer (score 6):

Despite [Shubham Arora's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39550125/6696558) is the best solution for this case, I'm going to show you how to do exactly what you asked with these two solutions that are quite simple:

#### 1. Global `boolean`

Create a global `boolean` and change it once your condition is met:

```
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    boolean processDone = false;

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists() && !processDone) {
            // do process 1   
        } else {
            // do process 2
            processDone = true;
        }
    }

    @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

#### 2. Remove listener

Remove your listener once your condition is met:

```
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            // do process 1   
        } else {
            // do process 2
            query.removeEventListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Both solutions did work fine for me when I was using `ChildEventListener` and [Shubham Arora's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39550125/6696558) couldn't help.